# Sum similar month objects from daily date in swift

Tags: swift

Guys my DB is structured to store daily steps data. I need to sum daily steps into monthly. here is my requirement as follows

```
//Daily Data from DB
let dailyData = [["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/04/28],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/04/29],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/04/30],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/04/01],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/05/02],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/05/03],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/05/04],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/05/05],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/06/06],
                 ["steps": 1000,
                  "date": 2018/06/07]]

//I need to sum daily data to monthly data as follows
let monthlyData = [["steps": 4000,
                    "month": April],
                   ["steps": 4000,
                    "month": May],
                   ["steps": 2000,
                    "month": June]]
```

Please help me with the logic. In daily data i have date type in both String and Date as well.

Comment: No, you need to put in more of an effort and show us what you have done so far and what your issue is. This is not a design and code writing service.

Comment: Group the array to a dictionary with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`, `map` the `steps` for each key and sum the values with `reduce`.

Comment: First of all you should use the `Date` type. 2018/04/28 will result in an integer. 2018/04 = 504, 504/28 = 18. So the value of your `date` key is 18.

Comment: I definitely recommend you use your database's data to initialize instance of a class or struct that better model your data. That'll be type safe and much easier to use, with no force unwrapping, no forced casting. From there, grouping by date with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` will be obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let dailyData: [[String: Any]] =
                    [["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/04/28"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/04/29"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/04/30"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/04/01"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/05/02"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/05/03"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/05/04"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/05/05"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/06/06"],
                     ["steps": 1000, "date": "2018/06/07"]]

    let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: dailyData, by: { ($0["date"] as! String).prefix(7) })
    let mappedDict = groupedDict.map { ["month": findMonth(str: String($0)), "steps": $1.map({ $0["steps"] ?? 0 }) ] }
    let result = mappedDict.map { ["month": $0["month"] ?? "", "steps": ($0["steps"] as! [Int]).reduce(0, { $0 + $1 }) ] }
    print(result)
```

where,

```
func findMonth(str: String) -> String {
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM"
    let date = dateformatter.date(from: str)!

    dateformatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    return dateformatter.string(from: date)
}
```

**Result is:**

```
[
 ["month": "June", "steps": 2000], 
 ["month": "April", "steps": 4000], 
 ["month": "May", "steps": 4000]
]
```

Comment: Clever use of prefix. (Voted.) You even used the new dictionary grouping function! I was thinking of using `split(separator:)` but prefix is simpler. Of course this solution will only work for this specific date format. A `DateFormatter` and DateComponents would be a more flexible solution.