# Filter an array by date in as section in tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, date, filter

I have a json like this

```
"myAlert": [{

    "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:45",
    "vs_title": "Kenya ",
    "vs_start_time": "2018-04-29 18:00:00",
    "vs_end_time": "2018-04-29 18:50:00",
    "vs_status": "1",
    "vs_add_time": "2018-04-29 00:00:00"
}, {

    "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:37",
    "vs_title": "Association",
    "vs_start_time": "2018-04-29 14:45:00",
    "vs_end_time": "2018-04-29 15:30:00",
    "vs_status": "1",
    "vs_add_time": "2018-04-29 00:00:00"
}, {
    "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:27",
    "vs_title": "Negotiations ",
    "vs_start_time": "2018-04-28 19:00:00",
    "vs_end_time": "2018-04-28 19:45:00",
    "vs_status": "1",
    "vs_add_time": "2018-04-28 00:00:00"
}, {
    "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:27",
    "vs_title": "Negotiations ",
    "vs_start_time": "2018-04-28 19:00:00",
    "vs_end_time": "2018-04-28 19:45:00",
    "vs_status": "1",
    "vs_add_time": "2018-04-28 00:00:00"
}]
```

I want to filter this data into `vs_add_time` . If the data have similar `vs_add_time` that date become as section and the data having the same date combine as dictionary into array of date.

I Want to filter data into this format:

```
"myAlert": [
     '2018-04-29': [{
         "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:45",
         "vs_title": "Kenya ",
         "vs_start_time": "2018-04-29 18:00:00",
         "vs_end_time": "2018-04-29 18:50:00",
         "vs_status": "1",
         "vs_add_time": "2018-04-29 00:00:00"
     }, {
         "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:41",
         "vs_title": "Kiyoshi El ",
         "vs_start_time": "2018-04-29 16:00:00",
         "vs_end_time": "2018-04-29 17:30:00",
         "vs_status": "1",
         "vs_add_time": "2018-04-29 00:00:00"
     }, ],
     '2018-04-28': [{
         "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:27",
         "vs_title": "Negotiations ",
         "vs_start_time": "2018-04-28 19:00:00",
         "vs_end_time": "2018-04-28 19:45:00",
         "vs_status": "1",
         "vs_add_time": "2018-04-28 00:00:00"
     }, {
         "usa_time": "2018-04-27 10:42:27",
         "vs_title": "Negotiations ",
         "vs_start_time": "2018-04-28 19:00:00",
         "vs_end_time": "2018-04-28 19:45:00",
         "vs_status": "1",
         "vs_add_time": "2018-04-28 00:00:00"
     }]
 ]
```

Can anyone put me on the right track?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `Dictionary(grouping:by:) ` to group the data. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193067/sum-similar-month-objects-from-daily-date-in-swift/50194728?noredirect=1#comment87415082_50194728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` for that, as:

```
let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: myAlert, by: { $0["vs_add_time"]! })
```

**Dictionary(grouping:by:)**

> Creates a new dictionary whose keys are the groupings returned by the given closure and whose values are arrays of the elements that returned each key.
>
> The arrays in the "values" position of the new dictionary each contain at least one element, with the elements in the same order as the source sequence.